# Giving environment variables as arguments

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I have a jar file that gets arguments from commandline and I want to give parameter that contains environment variable. Something like below:

```
java -jar MyDev.jar -f %PROJECT_HOME%/src/test
```

But in above case program creates a directory named `%PROJECT_HOME%` however I want that PROJECT_HOME value in system is `/home/jack` path. And program should follow `/home/jack/src/test` not `%PROJECT_HOME%/src/test` path.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Its entirely up to the shell to determine how to expand the command line arguments. Java could parse them further, but you are better off working out why your DOS shell is not behaving as expected.

Comment: I tried doing passing %USERPROFILE% to a simple one line test class which only prints the input argument to System.out. In my case, the variable was correctly translated into my home dir. Have you ensured that your variable is defined by doing `echo %PROJECT_HOME%` before starting the java program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running this in a Unix shell? If so, I suspect you just want:

```
java -jar MyDev.jar -f ${PROJECT_HOME}/src/test
```

Using `%` is the Windows way of specifying environment variables - which doesn't appear to fit with a home directory of `/home/jack`...

Comment: I am running on Windows, I gave /home/jack just for example.

Comment: @emin: It would have been helpful to be explicit about that to start with, and use a more representative example then... Are you running this just from a command prompt, or starting it some other way?

Answer (score 2):

The component responsible for environment variables substitution is the shell/command line processor (`cmd.exe` on Windows).

I wrote the following `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

When I pass "%PATH%" as an argument, running it from within Eclipse prints out `%PATH%`. Running it from the command line prints out the actual path environment variable.

Note that you can access environment variables from your Java code by using [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29).
For example, `System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"))` prints out the actual path variable both from Eclipse and from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

One very likely cause for this could be that the variable `PROJECT_HOME` is not defined or has a misspelled name. Hence, unless you have already done so, you should do `echo %PROJECT_HOME%` right before you start the java program in order to ensure that the variable is defined.